# Sequential access to hugepages in kernel driver

Tags: c, memory, linux-kernel, huge-pages

I'm working in a driver that uses a buffer backed by hugepages, and I'm finding some problems with the *sequentality* of the hugepages.

In userspace, the program allocates a big buffer backed by hugepages using the `mmap` syscall. The buffer is then communicated to the driver through a `ioctl` call. The driver uses the `get_user_pages` function to get the memory address of that buffer.

This works perfectly with a buffer size of 1 GB (1 hugepage). `get_user_pages` returns a lot of pages (`HUGE_PAGE_SIZE / PAGE_SIZE`) but they're all contigous, so there's no problem. I just grab the address of the first page with `page_address` and work with that. The driver can also map that buffer back to userspace with `remap_pfn_range` when another program does a `mmap` call on the char device.

However, things get complicated when the buffer is backed by more than one hugepage. It seems that the kernel can return a buffer backed by non-sequential hugepages. I.e, if the hugepage pool's layout is something like this

```
+------+------+------+------+
| HP 1 | HP 2 | HP 3 | HP 4 |
+------+------+------+------+
```

, a request for a hugepage-backed buffer could be fulfilled by reserving HP1 and HP4, or maybe HP3 and then HP2. That means that when I get the pages with `get_user_pages` in the last case, the address of page 0 is actually 1 GB after the address of page 262.144 (the next hugepage's head).

**Is there any way to *sequentalize* access to those pages?** I tried reordering the addresses to find the lower one so I can use the whole buffer (e.g., if kernel gives me a buffer backed by HP3, HP2 I use as base address the one of HP2), but it seems that would scramble the data in userspace (offset 0 in that *reordered* buffer is maybe offset 1GB in the userspace buffer).

TL;DR: Given >1 unordered hugepages, is there any way to access them sequentially in a Linux kernel driver?

By the way, I'm working on a Linux machine with 3.8.0-29-generic kernel.

Comment: Is it required that the buffer is allocated by user space?

Comment: No, it's not required, but I didn't find a clear way to do it inside of the kernel driver. Also, the fact that it's made this way allows us to choose more easily different hugepage sizes

Comment: Why do you care about the pysical addresses in the first place? Are you doing DMA?

Comment: @CL, as far as I've seen there's no way to get direct access to that buffer other than calling `page_address` on each page. I don't know if they're physical addresses or not (0xFFFFFC... doesn't seem much like a physical address, but I'm a newbie in kernel dev so I'm not sure about that). Either way, those addresses returned are not always continous.

About the second question, this buffer is not used for DMA, just for communication between driver and userspace.

Comment: Okay, what you care about are the kernel virtual addresses of the pages. The pages are not guaranteed to be contiguous unless you remap them, but it doesn't appear as if `vm_map_ram` works with huge pages.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! `vm_map_ram` solved the problem, it works with hugepages.

Comment: I thought it would always create 4 KB page table entries. If it works, please create an answer.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Using the function suggested by CL, [`vm_map_ram`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/htmldocs/kernel-api/API-vm-map-ram.html), I was able to remap the memory so it can be accesed sequentially, independently of the number of hugepages mapped. I leave the code here (error control not included) in case it helps anyone.

```
struct page** pages;
int retval;
unsigned long npages;
unsigned long buffer_start = (unsigned long) huge->addr; // Address from user-space map.
void* remapped;

npages =  1 + ((bufsize- 1) / PAGE_SIZE); 

pages = vmalloc(npages * sizeof(struct page *));

down_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);
retval = get_user_pages(current, current->mm, buffer_start, npages,
                     1 /* Write enable */, 0 /* Force */, pages, NULL);
up_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);    

nid = page_to_nid(pages[0]); // Remap on the same NUMA node.

remapped = vm_map_ram(pages, npages, nid, PAGE_KERNEL);

// Do work on remapped.
```