# use hugepages in kernel driver

Tags: linux-kernel, huge-pages

I refer to below two links to use huge page in my linux driver:

[Sequential access to hugepages in kernel driver](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25000494/sequential-access-to-hugepages-in-kernel-driver)
http://nuncaalaprimera.com/2014/using-hugepage-backed-buffers-in-linux-kernel-driver

Below is my code:

```
#define PAGE_SHIFT_2M   21
pages = vmalloc(nr_pages * sizeof(struct page*));

down_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);
get_nr_pages = get_user_pages(current, current->mm, buffer_start, nr_pages,
    1 /* Write enable */, 0 /* Force */, pages, NULL);
up_read(&current->mm->mmap_sem);

nid = page_to_nid(pages[0]);    // Remap on the same NUMA node.
remapped_addr = vm_map_ram(pages, nr_pages, nid, PAGE_KERNEL);

printf("page pfn [0]=%lX, [1]=0x%lX, [2]=0x%lX\n", 
    page_to_pfn(pages[0]), 
    page_to_pfn(pages[1]),
    page_to_pfn(pages[2]));
printf("page physical [0]=%lX, [1]=0x%lX, [2]=0x%lX\n", 
    page_to_pfn(pages[0])<<PAGE_SHIFT_2M, 
    page_to_pfn(pages[1])<<PAGE_SHIFT_2M,
    page_to_pfn(pages[2])<<PAGE_SHIFT_2M);
printf("page logical addr [0]=%p, [1]=%p, [2]=%p\n", 
    __va(page_to_pfn(pages[0])<<PAGE_SHIFT_2M), 
    __va(page_to_pfn(pages[1])<<PAGE_SHIFT_2M),
    __va(page_to_pfn(pages[2])<<PAGE_SHIFT_2M));
printf("page_address [0]=%p, [1]=%p, [2]=%p\n", 
    page_address(pages[0]), 
    page_address(pages[1]),
    page_address(pages[2]));
```

Log print:

page pfn [0]=154A00, [1]=0x154A01, [2]=0x154A02
page physical [0]=2A940000000, [1]=0x2A940200000, [2]=0x2A940400000
page logical addr [0]=ffff8aa940000000, [1]=ffff8aa940200000, [2]=ffff8aa940400000
page_address [0]=ffff880154a00000, [1]=ffff880154a01000, [2]=ffff880154a02000

I have several questions:
1) I'm wondering whether vm_map_ram() can works with huge page. From kernel source code, I can see vm_map_ram() use PAGE_SIZE and PAGE_SHIFT, which's value should for default 4KB page size.
In my case, after write to the virtual address returned from vm_map_ram(), I encounter "BUG: unable to handle kernel paging request at XXXX" issue.
2) page_address return values for two pages are 0x1000(4KB) gap, not 2MB gap. Why is that?
3)  Did I use right with "__va(page_to_pfn(pages[0])<

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I guess one may try `kmap` or `kmap_atomic` to map user-space process pages. Take a look how it can be done e.g. in `copy_strings` functions in kernel.

Comment: I had try kmap(), it just get the same address value as page_address(). Also I don't know if it works for huge page. There are lost of examples of use get_user_pages() and kmap(), but seems none for huge page.