# Can I allocate huge pages In Kernel driver?

Tags: c, linux, memory-management, linux-kernel, linux-device-driver

I want to allocate huge pages in kernel driver of size 2Mb. I have read that I can allocate huge page using kmalloc in this answer [Allocating huge pages in kernel modules](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55251790/allocating-huge-pages-in-kernel-modules).

Something like this.

```
kmalloc(0x200000, GFP_KERNEL | __GFP_COMP)
```

After doing this I am able to get the 2MB page but when I run the following command

```
cat /proc/meminfo | grep Huge
```

The number of Huge_pages_free remains same which means the request is not fulfilled using Huge pages allocated.

I also tried by doing this.

```
alloc_pages(GFP_TRANSHUGE, HPAGE_PMD_ORDER);
```

The results were same as above when I used kmalloc above.

Comment: `HugePages_xxx` fields in `/proc/meminfo` refer to *userspace hugetlb pages*, you won't see those numbers change after a kernel-side memory allocation.

Comment: Ok Thanks. I have one more question, So we can say that kernel does not allocate from HugePages to fulfill kernel space request. HugePages which I allocated using this cammond                                                                                                                # echo 1024 > /sys/kernel/mm/hugepages/hugepages-2048kB/nr_hugepages                  are only used to fulfill user space request?

Comment: Yes, those are for userspace. Kernel only uses *transparent* huge pages, which as the name implies are transparent so it's harder to distinguish them.

Comment: Ok Thanks. So if I want something like Hugepages which should be allocated for only kernel driver like total  memory of 1GB, I should use page_alloc or kmalloc functions?

Comment: I would assume so yeah, but I don't exactly know how.

Comment: Just allocate the memory without the __GFP_COMP. That's an internal flag mm uses to free properly, not for casual use. Let the mm code do the optimization for you. See khugepaged.

Comment: I think it would help if you explained why you want a huge page mapping in the kernel. Much of the time memory is mapped into the kernel address space using large pages already. If you want a physically contiguous memory block that is a different issue, and there are better ways to handle that.

Comment: @StuartMenefy In driver I want to allocate multiple 2MB contiguous buffers. I was looking for a way in which the the request to allocate 2MB contiguous buffers should pass every time. I was thinking that kmalloc maybe will fail after certain requests. So I was looking for method in which these requests would never fail. While reading online I read about huge page tables which are allocated at runtime so I thought If I use them then my request will pass every time because huge pages would be reserved. I want to a physically contiguous memory block not necessarily hugetlb pages.

Comment: The only way you can guarantee an allocation will never fail is to carve out enough physically contiguous memory when the system boots. Normally the best way to do this now is to use CMA - the Contiguous Memory Allocator. There is a (slightly out of date) description of this on [LWN](https://lwn.net/Articles/486301/). If you're using the DMA APIs to allocate coherent memory the the use of CMA is transparent, as long as you reserve memory (either globally or for your device) in the device tree.

Comment: @StuartMenefy If I allocate memory using DMA APIs then the use of CMA will be of no advantage. And then to guarantee allocation I have to reserve memory in the device tree for my device?

Comment: The DMA APIs (`dma_alloc_coherent()` for example) will use the CMA to allocate memory if possible, falling back to allocating from normal memory if that fails. I'm assuming you need large physically contiguous memory regions to meet DMA restrictions, is that correct? If you need to guarantee these allocations will succeed, reserving the memory when the system boots is really the only way to do this, and using the device tree is generally the easiest way to do that.

Comment: There are also kernel command-line options to reserve memory.

Comment: @StuartMenefy Yes that's correct, I need physically contiguous memory regions to meet DMA restrictions. Ok Thanks. So to confirm my understanding, please correct me if I am wrong. I need to reserve memory at the boot time and the device tree is the easiest way to do this. After reserving memory I have to point that memory for my device by somehow telling kernel that this memory is reserved for this device/driver. Is that correct?. And use that memory by dma api's.

Comment: That is correct. There is a good overview of this on the [Xilinx wiki](https://xilinx-wiki.atlassian.net/wiki/spaces/A/pages/18841683/Linux+Reserved+Memory#LinuxReservedMemory-ReservedmemorythroughDMAAPI) or search for drivers which call [of_reserved_mem_device_init](https://elixir.bootlin.com/linux/v6.5/source/include/linux/of_reserved_mem.h#L79) which is how you make the association between device and reserved memory region.

Comment: @StuartMenefy Thanks for help. just a follow up question Can I reserve memory using device tree in x86. I looked at the drivers that  use` of_reserved_mem_device_init` most of them are for arm. Just to clarify that in x86 also we can use Device tree to reserve memory?. Thanks

Comment: As far as I know this should work on an x86, there is nothing architecture specific about it, although I've never tried it. It tends not to be needed as most x86 platforms will have an IO-MMU between the peripheral and main memory, so while the peripheral sees a virtually contiguous block of memory it is actually physically dis-contiguous.